# How to simplify summations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I have the following expression:

$$ m_k= \frac 1 p \left( \frac{(S_{k-1})(S_0+S_1+\cdots+S_{N-2})}{S_{N-1}} - (S_0+S_1+\cdots+S_{k-2})\right)$$

where $k=1,2,\ldots,N-1$, and $S_k$=1+(q/p)+...+(q/p)^k

How can I simplify the expression?

Comment: i would downvote if i were mean. please make it clearer, what do you need?

Comment: isn't it clear? how come? :( @gebra

Comment: What is $S_k$ here? If we know what it is, we can use that to simplify the expression more than simply factoring out $S_0+...+S_{N-2}$

Comment: @Vedvart1 yep, I edited my question

Comment: @RossMillikan yes it's the same, sorry

Comment: also, maybe add context? the question on its own seems pretty obscure

Answer (score 0):

You can start by using the fact that $S_k=\frac{(\frac qp)^{k+1}-1}{\frac qp-1}$ because your expression is a geometric series.  Then your sums of $S$s will include geometric series as well.

Comment: I tried using this fact first but the expression was a little complicated so I tried to simplify first the expression above (my question) and then replace the geometric serie